# How can I use par2 to mimick the parity of RAID arrays?

Tags: linux, backup, raid, storage, tape

**Background:**

I'm using LTO-8 tapes and my concern is that over time, the data on the tape can become corrupted and the goal that I am trying to accomplish is to use par2 to create the parity that I may be able to use in the future to try and restore/repair/recover any data that might end up being corrupted on said LTO-8 tape.

**Here is my thought process/approach:**

I was thinking about how RAID5/raidz will use 1 drive for parity data (which I think that in traditional RAID5, the parity would then be stripped acrossed the RAID array).

In par2, there is a command flag "-r" where you can set the parity level and/or amount of parity to be created.

That I understand.

But the part that I don't understand is if I use that flag with a file, and it will create the .par2 files, would that be the same as "RAID5"/"raidz" or is my entire thought process and approach of trying to accomplish the similar effect completely wrong?

I know that the LTO-8 tape itself will I think do some checksumming, but what I am less sure of it is if there is a problem with the checksum, how it will either repair itself (if it has that capability -- I haven't seen any documentation from reading about LTFS that says that it can but I also haven't read nor seen any documentation that says that it CAN'T either).

And if it CAN'T repair itself (or I assume that to be the worst case scenario), would using par2 be sufficient to protect the tape from data corruption?

Also, the way that I have currently set it up is that the .par2 files are also written to the same tape (and then I have a father-son structure in regards to the tape backup themselves, e.g. duplicate copies).

If I can have parity data instead, then I would free up half of my tapes that I can use for other data instead of using the father-son/duplicate backup structure instead.

Any thoughts, ideas, and/or insights as to how I may accomplish this is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: That question may be more appropriate on Server Fault, as it is not specific to Unix nor Linux.

Comment: @Totor we don't require things to be specific to Unix or Linux, only that they are _applicable_ to Unix or Linux. Since the OP is clearly on a *nix system, this is completely on topic.

Comment: Thanks @terdon, I get that it needs to be applicable and not specific. Could you quote a sentence from the OP where it is clear that s·he is on a *nix system as I fail to get this.

Comment: @Totor for one thing, they posted here. And isn't `par2` a *nix thing anyway? More importantly, even if the OP isn't using *nix, the question is entirely applicable to *nix, so it can stay. But yes, you're right, I don't know where I got the "clearly". I guess from the style, but on second reading it isn't as clear as all that.

Comment: @terdon [`par2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) is rather a spec with multi-OS implementations than a *nix thing. It is nevertheless applicable to *nix.

Comment: Perhaps to add clarity - yes, I am using a mix of CentOS, and Kubuntu (I guess, technically) for this.

I haven't found a way to get LTFS to work with Windows without paying an exorbinant fee for the software whereas you can download, build/compile, and install LTFS on Linux for free and by reading the BUILDING.linux file.

My apologies for not specifying.

(I forget if there's a precompiled binary for par2 (other than QuickPar) where you can use the command line options. I looked at it very briefly but since my cluster, headnode, the tape drive system all run Linux, this is why I'm here

Answer (score 2):

## How `par2` works

With `par2` you can select the percentage of parity you want to compute over a given set of data files. It internally splits the whole dataset into **chunks** to compute parity information on those chunks. So **its basic unit of work is the chunk** (for integrity checking and data reconstruction).

Its algorithm is indeed similar to some RAID algorithms, but more sophisticated than classic RAID5, in that any parity chunk can be used to restore any corrupted data chunk. It uses [Reed-Solomon error-correcting codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction) and that needs more computing!

If two different chunks are *very slightly* corrupted, you will still need 2 parity chunks to recover data. On the other hand, if 1 chunk is *completely* corrupted, you will only need 1 parity chunk to recover. So chunk size can be something you want to consider accordingly.

Also, corrupted `par2` files that are partially readable can still play a role in data recovery, if some of the parity information within them can still be read.

Then, it is designed to work with (corrupted) *files* (and not datastreams).

## Example

So you may choose to have:

```
FULL DATASET + 20% par2 parity files
```

That would mean you can lose approx. the equivalent of 20% of your data-*chunks*.

## Things to consider for decision making

Then it is up to you to choose :

- the size of the full dataset (the bigger, the more computing resources needed for recovery and parity construction),
- the percentage of parity you want to compute,
- the physical location of the parity and data,
- the chunk size,

Knowing that:

- you need the full (corrupted) dataset+par2_data to perform a repair, and this repair needs to be performed on disk,
- you need a non negligible amount of CPU power to repair,
- your tape reader/writer & software may have specific behavior around unreadable data that may or may not help you recover.

## Some possibilities

If your tape reader is able to replace unreadable bytes by, say, bytes equal to 0, then it could make sense I guess to store `par2` files on the same tape, as that would make the recovery process easier, than say, having the whole corrupted file missing when trying to transfer it on disk.

If you are considering the risk of losing one full tape though, then you do need parity files that are computed over several tapes datasets, and you want at least as much parity data as what the biggest tape holds. For recovery, you will need to transfer the remaining tapes data to disk, along with the parity data to reconstruct the missing tape data.

## Conclusion

`par2` is pretty flexible so, it's all up to you and the data loss scenarios you want to be protected from.

`par2` does not work like classic RAID parity and was not built for that purpose. RAID parity recovery is faster because a specific data block on disk has a specific dedicated parity block on another disk, while any `par2` parity chunk can recover any other corrupted chunk through a more sophisticated and costly process.

So, you may want to consider the duration of repairing. It can be really long to recover corrupted data with par2 on "big" datasets. I recommend some testing before deciding.

`par2` can still be used for redundancy and data loss prevention, but with the above considerations.

Comment: Thank you.

Yeah, so far I'm just leaving the chunk size at the default that par2 calculates as a function of the dataset size.

(I forget what the calculation is, but as I vaguely recall reading, par2 has a finite limit on the number of chunks, IIRC, and therefore; as I also vaguely recall, they said that for a large dataset to not to set the chunk size to be too small.)

I've been using the defaults for now.

Comment: And yes, whenever I am doing anything with the data from the tapes, I am transferring the files to disk and doing all of the data processing operations on disk before writing it back to tape.

Thank you.

Yeah, it's too bad that unlike RAID, it's a lot easier for a RAID array to grab the parity data from the drives in the array whenever it needs to. If I distribute the parity data across different tapes, to do the same, it would be a vastly longer process, due in part to load/unload, fast forward/rewind of the tape itself.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm okay with the computational requirements of the data processing. I have some experience with how much computational power is needed to generate the .par2 files, depending on the size of the dataset that it is computing the parity for.

Comment: If that is so, `par2` may be the appropiate tool for you. :) I added a wp link to the Reed-Solomon algorithm that `par2` is using in my answer. Please upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied with it.